# NoClassDefFound Error but the class is there? Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, pdfbox, noclassdeffounderror

The below code throws "NoClassDefFound" error at PDDocument document

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


   // Specify the input PDF file
        String inputPDF = "C:\\Users\\Chris-Whpr\\Documents\\input.pdf";
       
        // Specify the output PDF file
        String outputPDF = "output.pdf";

        try {
            // Load the existing PDF document
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(inputPDF));
```

The PDFBox jar has been added to my library correctly and imports without error.

I tried closing/opening Netbeans but no dice.

Comment: Which jar file did you use? Did you verify the checksum?